# play framework - connect to linux mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am new play framework. I am trying to connect to mysql database on linux server. it is not working !!

I am getting an error:

> A database error occured : Cannot connected to the database, Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

anyway I am able to connect linux server through my MySQL Work bench.

```
application.mode=dev
%prod.application.mode=prod

jpa.ddl=update

db.url=jdbc:mysql://<ipaddress>:3306/<database>?useUnicode=false&characterEncoding=ISO-8859-1&connectionCollation=utf8_swedish_ci
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.user=<user>
db.pass=<password>
```

Comment: Do you really has to show as whole config? 200+ lines of comments, where maybe important are just 4 lines?

Comment: @biesior, sorry for that. I am removing unnecessary code !!

Comment: Also please, write more what is tha mean it's not working... check your logs and if you won't find an answer most probably you'll find some clue. Try to describe problem more

Comment: I will check logs but I am getting an error - "A database error occured : Cannot connected to the database, Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."

Answer (score 1):

ensure that you have the correct ip address and port nunmber for mysql in the config file (as well as the correct username/pwd).

you can check if mysql is listening on the port (try netstat -an | grep 3306).

Comment: Hi, I can connect to the server through MySQL work bench. So, I think there won't be problem with username, password and ip.

Comment: so I take it you passed in those values in the config file?

Comment: Yes, I passed the same values.